# NET/Silverlight: Immutable objects and the DataContractSerializer

Tags: .net, silverlight

Is there any way to make the DataContractSerializer play nicely with immutable objects?

There are a lot of situations where public setters are simply not appropriate but I still need a way to serialize them. Currently I am hand-writing XML that can be passed to the constructors, but that is very error prone and icky.

Answer (score 1):

The nature of data contract serialization is that the objects being "serialised" are treated as black boxes.  The serializer can only use that which is made visible on the surface of the object.  In fact its not accurate to say that the objects are being serialised, its the data contract that is being serialised.

One approach is to make the setters internal rather than public.  You then add a InternalsVisibleToAttribute to the assembly specifying the System.Runtime.Serialization assembly.  Using this approach provides some control  over member accessibility.

Answer (score 0):

We encountered the same problem, and our solution was to have two sets of classes - the "Data Contract" classes, and the "API" classes.  Each data contract class would have all the fields that required serialization, and nothing else (i.e. no methods or logic of any kind).  An API class would wrap a data contract class, and this is what we exposed in our API.

For example:

```
namespace MyApp.DataContracts 
{

  /// <summary>
  /// This class is part of the application infrastructure and is 
  /// not intended to be used from your code.
  /// </summary>
  /// <exclude />
  [DataContract]
  [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
  public class PersonData
  {
     [DataMember] public string firstName;
     [DataMember] public string lastName;
  }
}

namespace MyApp
{
  public class Person
  {
    private PersonData _data;

    public Person() 
      : this(new PersonData())
    {
    }

    internal Person(PersonData data) {
      this._data = data;
    }

    public FirstName {
      get { return this._data.firstName; }
      private set { this._data.firstName = value; }
    }

    public LastName {
      get { return this._data.lastName; }
      private set { this._data.lastName = value; }
    }

    public void Save() {
      // Code that serializes our PersonData and sends it to the server
    }

  }
}
```